# Angular Animation error when routing to external module [Cannot read property 'play' of undefined]

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I have components that are being loaded into the DOM using Angular animations. The router links all work when the router outlet and the route are part of the same parent module. I get this error though when a router link is clicked that navigates to a cross module.

module A -> all routes work with animations

module B -> all routes work with animations

module B route to module A -> errors

> logging-error-handler.js:37 Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
>
> logging-error-handler.js:37 Uncaught (in promise): 
>       NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 
>       Partial keyframes are not supported.

I think it may have something to do with the animation not knowing which router-outlet to watch. However I thought the `void` keyword was a special keyword that would resolve when found.

```
animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [
        state('*',
            style({
                opacity: 1
            })
        ),
        transition('void => *', [
            style({
                opacity: 0,
                transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
            }),
            animate('0.8s ease-in')
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate('0.8s ease-out', style({
                opacity: 0,
                transform: 'translateY(100%)'
            }))
        ])
    ])
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a fake animation to module A and module B. Just write this:

```
animations: [
    trigger('routeAnimation', [])
]
```

It is not a beautiful solution, but works for me